# C doesn't printf in for loop

Tags: c, for-loop, printf

I am new in C and I am doing some basic stuff.
I am doing a simple quiz and for some reason, it doesn't work when I try to print the options for the question.

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "app.h"

int main(void){
    startQuiz();
    return 0;
}
```

**app.h**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int Question(char text[100], char options[4][40], int rightAns);

void startQuiz(void){
    char q1[4][40] = {
        {'"', 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '"'},
        {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd'},
        {'p', 'r', 'i', 'n', 't', '(', '\'', 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '\'', ')'},
        {'\'', 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '\''}
    };

    char q2[4][40] = {
        {'g', 'e', 't', '_', 't', 'y', 'p', 'e', '(', 'x', ')'},
        {'p', 'r', 'i', 'n', 't', '(', 'x', ')'},
        {'x', '.', 't', 'y', 'p', 'e'},
        {'t', 'y', 'p', 'e', '(', 'x', ')'}
    };

    char q3[4][40] = {
        {'x'},
        {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '_', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd'},
        {'e', 'x', 'e', 'c'},
        {'c', 'o', 'm', 'm', 'a', 'n', 'd'}
    };

    int Q1 = Question("what is the output of `print('hello world')`", q1, 2);
    int Q2 = Question("how to get a type of a variable?", q2, 4);
    int Q3 = Question("choose a not valid name for argument in python", q3, 3);

    printf("you got: %d / 3\n", Q1 +Q2 +Q3);
};


int Question(char text[100], char options[4][40], int rightAns){
    int ans;

    printf("\n%s.\n", text);
    for(int i; i<4; i++){
        printf("%d. %s\n", i+1, options[i]);
        // I dont want to add to i I just want to print i+1

    }printf(">>> ");
    scanf("%d", &ans);

    if(ans==rightAns){
        return 1;
    }return 0;
};
```

It is supposed to be a quiz and the output I get is:

[image]

It doesn't print the options that I gave it:

Comment: @4386427
 ahh thx but C give `int i;` a value of 0 as default no?

Comment: Initialize the arrays using strings `"\"hello world\""` rather than writing each character separately.  Don't include whole function bodies in header files, in general (if you do, make sure they are `inline` and that you're using `inline` correctly).  Put the function declaration in the header; place the function definition in a source file — and compile and link both source files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(int i; i<4; i++){
```

Since you don't assign a value to `i`, it could have any value. This is known as undefined behaviour. You should always ensure a variable has a value before it is used.

This should fix your code...

```
for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
```

Also, the way you initialise your options is really hard to read. You can put in strings rather than listing each individual character.

```
char q1[4][40] = {
    "\"hello world\"",
    "hello world",
    // etc....
};
```